# Wrongly set the JAVA_HOME in mac

Tags: java, macos, java-home

I changed the Java home of my mac from Java 10 to Java 8 by using the below comment:

```
echo export "JAVA_HOME=\$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

But unfortunately, when I wun the command I put 1.7 instead of 1.8:

```
echo export "JAVA_HOME=\$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7)" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Now when I am opening the terminal getting the below error:
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.7".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open you `.bash_profile` file with your favorite text editor and look at the last line. It should be

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7)
```

Change the `1.7` to `1.8` and you should be OK.

Comment: Anyone struggling to configure java in macos catalina: remove any JDKs previously installed `sudo rm -fr /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-<desired version>.jdk`. Download jre and jdk of the same version `jre-8u251-macosx-x64.dmg` and `jdk-8u251-macosx-x64.dmg` and install them. Installing process needs to allow installation in System Preferences > Security & Privacy > General > Open anyway button. When opening a new Terminal, enter `java -version` and you will get something as "java version 1.8.0_251".